# Accessing MAP key value pair during runtime in karate

Tags: karate

I have map object

```
{
  "101": "444",
  "102": "4442"
}
```

I need to access only values "444" or "4442" based on their respective keys . Is there any way to do this

I tried by mapping it to array and then acccessing array , but looking for better way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm not understanding the question, but this should work:

```
* def data = { '101': '444', '102': '4442' }
* def first = data['101']
* def second = data['102']
```